# How can I use standard SQL on text fields of elastic without using the specials SQL elasticSearch operators?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to create SQL query on some text field (not keyword) for example "name" field and send that query to elastic server.

my problem is that I need to use the standard SQL language (not the MATCH and QUERY operators which are specials for elastic SQL) of text fields.

when I tried to use JDBC driver or when I tried to use high-level-java-client with LIKE operatorI got the following error

```
  "No keyword/multi-field defined exact matches for [name]; define one or use MATCH/QUERY instead"
```

I also tried to use the translate API of elasticsearch- but even there I couldn't use the "LIKE" operator on text fields only on keyword fields.

does anyone have any solution for me? I want to use the LIKE operator on text fields instead of the full text operators which are unique to elastic sql.

Comment: You can check out https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-translate.html#sql-translate

Comment: I am getting the same error here as well.. it does not let me use standard SQL operators on text feilds. I cannot do "name LIKE something" if my collumn is of type text and not keyword

Comment: @Ohad please check below my answer annd if it helps you then upvote and marked as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-like-rlike-operators.html) documentation. they have clearly mentioned in document that it is not possible.

> One significant difference between LIKE/RLIKE and the full-text search
> predicates is that the former act on exact fields while the latter
> also work on analyzed fields. **If the field used with LIKE/RLIKE
> doesn’t have an exact not-normalized sub-field (of keyword type)**
> **Elasticsearch SQL will not be able to run the query**. If the field is
> either exact or has an exact sub-field, it will use it as is, or it
> will automatically use the exact sub-field even if it wasn’t
> explicitly specified in the statement.

If you still want to used text field then you need to enabled multi-field as mentioned [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-data-types.html#sql-multi-field). or you can try out to enable `fielddata` on text field but i am not sure that it will work SQL or not.